# How to completely delete entities from a DbSet after first deleting entities on the database via raw SQL?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 and have encountered some performance problems when dealing with large numbers of entities. Specifically, calling  `RemoveRange(...)` and  `SaveChanges()` takes way too much time in my scenario to delete entities.

This has led me to create some code to perform a 'Bulk' operation for Delete which uses raw SQL and does not use the `DbContext` or `DbSets`.

However, since the 'Bulk' operation is not made through the `DbContext / DbSet`, I need to mirror the changes made via the raw SQL so that the `DbContext / DbSet` and the database are back in sync with each other.

Basically, I want to make it such that, after the raw `DELETE` SQL has run, it's as if the deleted entities had never existed in the `DbSet`.

It's no good calling

`DbSet<T>().RemoveRange(...)`

as all this will do is mark the entities with a `Deleted` state, such that when the next `SaveChanges()` happens, the `DbContext` will try to update the database for entities that have already been deleted via raw SQL.

So, my next thought was to set the `EntityState` for each deleted entity in the `DbSet` to `Detached`?

But as far as I can tell, this only changes the entities' state so that they are not tracked by the `DbContext`, and the entities still remain in the `DbSet`. I would like them to be removed completely.

So, is there a way to change my `DbSet` so that:

1. the deleted entities are removed from the `DbSet` completely

AND

2. there are no pending changes to be sent to the database after the next `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

AND

3. without calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()`

Thanks.

Comment: Just  dispose your dbcontext after your raw SQL executes, then new it up again.

Comment: @mxmissile, that's not really an option since I'll then have the time penalty of reloading all the other entities back into the `DbContext`.